# Why do we use redirect in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

Why do people have to redirect at all if the url is in their own web application?
Why in Spring people redirect from Controller's handler method to another handler method in the same controller?
I have heard that redirect is browser based. It is like sending request to the browser to send a request to another URL.
While forward makes sense as it is used fro within the (spring mvc) application so that the URL on browser's window remains the same.

But is it heroic to use redirect:/url when you can simply send a view name or use forward if need be.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `redirect` prefix in your controller will generate a HTTP response with the [302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) status code and the location header pointing to the redirection URL. The browser will then redirect to that URL (model exposed in the first request will be lost, and the browser URL will be the second one).

Using the `forward` prefix, the forward will be done internally by the servlet, so there's no need of a second request (URL will remain the same). The `forward` prefix should only be used in **requests that can be safely repeated by the browser**. That's not the case when you send a form which changes the database state (reloading the browser will lead to duplicate submissions). In these cases you should use `redirect` and apply the POST-redirect-GET pattern. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 2):

Without specific context, it's hard to tell you all the reasons why some one would use a redirect after execution of a handler.

There are some situations where a redirect after handler processing (e.g. after a POST) are considered a desired design pattern - [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

One common problem is duplicate form submission with POST method. By using a redirect after processing the form, an application can for the most part prevent the user from hitting refresh and re-submitting the form - as they are now at the newly redirected url.

Answer (score 1):

We do the redirect instead of forward to a page because we want to apply the redirect-after-post pattern to our form submission.

With this pattern, a successful form submission issues an HTTP redirect to avoid resubmissions if the user reloads or bookmark the page.