# RedirectAttributes in Spring MVC 3.2.8

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

I have this method

```
@RequestMapping(value = {       "/newdesign/manage/device/award",
                                    "/newdesign/manage/device/award/"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String awardDeviceProduct(                               
                                     @ModelAttribute("deviceForm") DeviceForm deviceForm,                                                               
                                     HttpServletRequest request,
                                     Model model,
                                     final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {

        checkUser (request, UserRole.MARKETING);

        Device device =   manageLicenseService.getDeviceById(deviceForm.getDevice().getId());


        if (deviceForm.getDevice().getIos()==null) {

            model.addAttribute ("errorMessage", "Licence Number cannot be null !");

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Licence Number cannot be null !");

        } else if (deviceForm.getSelectedItems()!=null &&
                !deviceForm.getSelectedItems().isEmpty()) {     

            // check LICENCE DUPLICATED

            manageLicenseService.applyStatusChange (device, deviceForm.getSelectedItems(), Status.AWARDED );


        } else {

            model.addAttribute ("errorMessage", "no Items selected !");
            model.addAttribute ("productGroup",     getNotExpiredProductGroups (request));

        }


        return "redirect:/newdesign/manage/device/" + deviceForm.getDevice().getId();


    }
```

But in the JSP I can't find the attribute "errorMessage" !!!! when (deviceForm.getDevice().getIos()==null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code relies in the difference between "redirect" and "forward".

If you return with a redirect statement, the response will first return to the browser, and then it will request the new url. The problem with this approach is, that the redirected new request will have a completely new context, and will not have access to the Model, set in your previous response.

The forward response however is processed by the server side itself, transferring the request to the new URL. It is faster and the context can be maintained.

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29560927/2019459)